# spring security ldap surname validation

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I am doing ldap authentication using spring security.
In our Active Directory , we have sn ( surname ) defined as blank for some of the users and LDAP authentication is failing for those users.
I found that it is because of the below code

```
package org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails;
public class Person extends LdapUserDetailsImpl {
      public LdapUserDetails createUserDetails() {
            Person p = (Person) super.createUserDetails();
            Assert.hasLength(p.sn);
            Assert.notNull(p.cn);
            Assert.notEmpty(p.cn);
            // TODO: Check contents for null entries
            return p;
        }
}
```

Has anybody faced this problem ? Is it possible to avoid the length check for surname  using configuration or extending the Person Class ?

Thanks

Lives

Comment: Yes, I faced the same problem. Wondering why sn needs to be required.

Comment: Resolved by extending the spring person class

Comment: I created a Jira for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2757

Comment: This is now fixed in Spring Security 4.2.0.M1 by this Pull Request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/200